# How to reload Logger when appsetting.json has reloaded?

Tags: c#, nlog

I'm trying to control LogLevel in log from appsetting.json. I've added my Nlog config here and custom field LogLevel. In rules I've added `"${configsetting:item=LogLevel}"` and it works. But I want to be able to change LogLevel when app is running. So I add `autoReload` to json and `reloadOnChange = true` to ConfigurationBuilder. But it's not working for NLog.

Some of `appsetting.json`:

```
  "LogLevel": "Info",
  "NLog": {
    "throwConfigExceptions": true,
    "autoReload": true,
    "internalLogToConsole": true,
    "extensions": [
      { "assembly": "SumoLogic.Logging.NLog" }
    ],
    "targets": {
      "async": true,
      "fileTarget": {
        "type": "File",
        "fileName": "${gdc:item=mainLogFileName}",
        "layout":"${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message:exceptionSeparator=\r\n:withException=true}"
      },
      "errorFileTarget": {
        "type": "File",
        "fileName": "${gdc:item=errorLogFileName}",
        "layout":"${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message:exceptionSeparator=\r\n:withException=true}"
      },
      "consoleTarget": {
        "type": "Console",
        "layout":"${message:exceptionSeparator=\r\n:withException=true}"
      }
    },
    "rules": [
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "minLevel": "${configsetting:item=LogLevel}",
        "writeTo": "consoleTarget"
      },
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "minLevel": "${configsetting:item=LogLevel}",
        "writeTo": "fileTarget"
      },
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "minLevel": "Error",
        "writeTo": "errorFileTarget"
      },   
    ]
  }
```

And my code is

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
    .AddCommandLine(args)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .AddUserSecrets(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
    .Build();

ConfigSettingLayoutRenderer.DefaultConfiguration = config;
LogManager.Configuration = new NLogLoggingConfiguration(config.GetSection("NLog"));

LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
```

The only way it works for me:

```
_logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
                
ConfigSettingLayoutRenderer.DefaultConfiguration = _config;
                
LogManager.Configuration = new NLogLoggingConfiguration(_config.GetSection("NLog"));

LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
```

but it means to write it under every log.

Is there any nice way to reload NLog with appsetting?

Comment: NLogLoggingConfiguration should support `"autoReload": true` out of the box without needing extra help. It just requires that `AddJsonFile` uses `reloadOnChange = true`. Could you [create a new issue here](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/issues) and attach an example project that reproduces the issue with reload not working when updating `appsettings.json`-file ?

Comment: @Rolf added to https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/issues/592

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but overall it’s a bad practice trying to replace appsettings during the application runtime. It suppose to be deployed along with the service and to be read / buffered on application startup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to update the appsettings.json file that has been "deployed" with your application. Ex. in Debug- or Release- output-folder.

Microsoft Extension Logging will not react to updating appsettings.json in the Visual Studio Solution-folder.